# Ruby Method without Quotes

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a ruby method that takes a string input but I don't want to type the quotes.

For example:

```
def noquotes(input)
  puts input
end

noquotes('12Dec11Bel01')  # --->  12Dec11Bel01

noquotes(12Dec11Bel01)  # --->  Currently yields an error
```

What I'd like to be able to do is enter the method input without the quotes (second example) and still get the right result.   I tried using .to_str to ensure the input was treated as a string, but it didn't work.

Comment: you cant. but i am curious to know WHY hate the quotes? they tell the system you're dealing with strings. Do you want to use symbols? stick a colon ":" in front of the 12Dec11Be101 then call the method.

Comment: down the road, I was thinking of doing some sort of dsl and want it to be very simple. Plus I have a real problem hitting those quotes. I like your idea on the symbol. I'm pretty good with the colon sign. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hehe, sorry, but you can't mangle with the syntax tree in Ruby. If you don't make quotes, it will be parsed as a variable or method call.

What you can do is

```
def method_missing(meth, *args)
  meth.to_s
end
```

but use that wisely and with scoping, as in

```
class DSL # You'd use that here
  def dsl(&block)
    instance_eval(block)
  end
  def method_missing(meth, *args)
    meth.to_s
  end
  def noquotes(input)
    puts input
  end
end

def dsl(&block)
  DSL.new.dsl(&block)
end

dsl do
  noquotes(foobar)
end
```

Use with caution and only if you know what you're doing! And only in DSL. And not even there. Really. Don't do it.

Comment: This is a smart way of doing things. It could bite super hard, esp. if what you pass into `noquotes` contains spaces and/or reserved ruby words.

Comment: Nice answer. +1 for "Really. Don't do it" ;)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible without doing horrible maintainence-nightmare things. Think about how the Ruby interpreter needs to parse your input. Without the quotes, it has no way to know that `12Dec11Bel01` is intended as a string, and not a call to another method or the name of a variable.

Type the quotes as skip the parentheses. It's the same number of characters.